# angular auto bootstrap mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I seem unable to get a named angular application to auto-bootstrap inside of a view in an MVC application.  I can use the ng-app directive to work.  I can even get it to work naming the application ng-app="".

I cannot seem to get a named application / module to resolve inside of an MVC partial view (_layout.cshtml).

Comment: Please add a minimal example of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng-app in the html tag for a single page app, or, load it into the div of choice

```
<html ng-app="namedApp">
</html>
```

Your angular app module needs a name:

```
var app = angular.module("namedApp", ['ngRoute']);
```

I don't know if you're already doing this, but this works every time for me.